# Rails: How to filter table records during a period?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

model Express has an attribute "date"
In the Index page, I hope to filter out express information during a period,
what technology can be used here?
I searched railscast 240 "Search, Sort, Paginate with AJAX", but it did cover this.

what I want basically like this. When the first time index page is loaded no record shows,until I set a period and click search button it will show records.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send HTTP GET or POST request to your index method with two params date_from and date_to. You can do it with jQuery.ajax() method or with vanila form_for and submit. Then in your index method you can do smth like this:

```
def index    
  @expresses = Express.where(date: params[:date_from]..params[:date_to]) if params[:date_from] && params[:date_to]
end
```